# Single user registration vs multiple users registration form

Tags: forms, registration, signup-signon, accordion

I'm working on a registration process and have wireframed a single user registration process (see below my wireframes).
We want to promote our product and encourage users to invite others. In a first time, we thought of offering the option to invite colleagues/friends at the end of the process. However, we want to explore other options, in particular the possibility to invite people as part of the process.

How would you imagine that?

Some ideas:

- a switch between single user and multiple users registration
- an 'add user' link/button at the first step

[image: Registration process]

Comment: I don’t know the purpose of your application but I guess you’ll explain to your users why you insist on a multiple users sign up. Because offering an option to allow people inviting colleagues and friends in the ongoing process rather than at the end is quite a heavy lifting thanks to additional steps the user has to take (e.g. remember email addresses, confirm access to contacts). I guess you should wrap it up in a consistent user story during the onboarding process to communicate the reason for this option.

Comment: It's a subscription-based newspaper.

Answer (score 4):

Let focus the user on a single task, the registration. 
Then ask the user to invite others – colleagues and friends – in order to share the same experience. 
The *onboarding* is a very critical step and if you add too many features the risk is that the final user experience get complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea appears like Amazon asking you to leave a review on a product in your basket during the checkout stage.

## Registration as means to end

Registering is a step users are forced to take in order to access what's after the registration process. In other words, the **goal** is to get to the system, and registration is just a barrier - a required step.

## A critical conversion point

Registration screens are one of the places where conversions can be greatly affected, and generally the quicker the user goes through the process and the less work they have to do or information to provide - the higher the conversion rate.

## Would you recommend something you have not tried yet?

What's more, why would anyone like to recommend a product to friends before experiencing the product? A user may think:

> I'm registering so I can try your product, so how do you expect me to recommend it now?

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree to the other two answers (I upvoted them for that). Don't add more steps to the registration!

You're probably asking "When should users invite other people, then?" Since you say this is a newspaper, I think there's a perfect point in time: Together with an article, you present the option to share the article with someone. The user may have the urge to forward the information, or even pass on some comment together with the link (I often miss this possibility), and this is the time when you can ask for an email (or whatever else you want to know) of another user.

- Registration is as quick as possible
- Invitation/Recommendation has a reason ("this article is interesting for you")
- Invitation opportunities occur often